# Check user input against json list strings

Tags: python, html, json

I am developing a guess the answer from an image game for a project. The images and correct answers are stored in a list in a json file. The images are randomly rendered on the game page, where the player inputs their answer. I am trying to find a way to compare the users answers with the randomly generated image. Below are some of the items in the list

```
{
"players": [

{
    "image_source": "static/img/portfolio/neymar.jpg",
    "answer": "Neymar"
},

{
    "image_source": "static/img/portfolio/hugo_lloris.jpg",
    "answer": Lloris"
},

{
    "image_source": "static/img/portfolio/lorenzo_insigne.jpg",
    "answer": "Insigne"
}
```

The user enters the answer in a form on the html page. As the images are randomly generated this is not as straight forward as I hoped.

My initial attempt uses Jinja and hidden forms:

```
<img class="img-fluid" {{ loop.index }}. src="{{ player.image_source }}" alt="player image">
     <form method="POST">
         <div class="control-group">
            <div class="hidden_form">
                <textarea rows="1" 
                 id="question_number" name="question_number" 
                 type="hidden" value="{{ loop.index }}">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden_form">
               <textarea rows="1" 
                id="answer" name="answer" 
                type="hidden" value="{{ player.answer }}">
               </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group 
            floating-label-form-group answers controls pb-2">
                <textarea rows="1" class="form-control" 
                 id="user_answer" name="user_answer" 
                 type="text" placeholder="Enter Answer" 
                 required="required" 
                 data-validation-required-message="Please enter your answer.">
                </textarea>
            </div>
```

However, I would like to avoid using the hidden forms as I find this a little messy.

My Python code is:

```
@app.route('/play', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def answers():
    if session:
        if request.method == "POST":
            session['question_number'] +=1
            session['guess'] = request.form.get("user_answer")
            session['correct_answer'] = request.form.get("answer")
            if session['guess'] == session['correct_answer']:
                flash('Correct!')
            else:
                flash('Incorrect, please try again or skip to the next question')
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Did you break down the problem into smaller chunks yet? This, as is, is too broad.

Comment: Try using pandas DataFrame to load the json file into your program. And then you can perform a lot of operations on that without having to use loops and all.